# How to prove that, if $G$ has an average node degree $\geq 6$ then $G$ cannot be planar

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> Let $G= (V,E)$ simple, connected , undirected graph. Show that, if $G$ has an average node degree $\frac{1}{|V|}\sum_{v\in V} d(v) \geq 6$, then $G$ cannot be planar.

Comment: The average node degree is $2E/V$. Plug into Euler's formula, remembering that each face (of a simple graph!) has at least three sides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. If $G$ is planar and connected, by [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Euler's_formula), $|V|-|E|+|F|=2$. Now $G$ is simple and each face has at least three edges (provided there are at least three edges, see tomasz's comment  and my P.S. below), therefore $3|F|\leq 2|E|$ and
$$2=|V|-|E|+|F|\leq |V|-|E|+2|E|/3\implies |E|\leq 3|V|−6.$$
Finally use the fact that in any graph, $\sum_{v\in V}d(v)=2|E|$.

P.S. Note that $\frac{1}{|V|}\sum_{v\in V} d(v)=\frac{2|E|}{|V|} \geq 6$ implies that $|E|\geq 3$.

Comment: So I first have to assume the G is planar. Ah makes alot more sense thank you

Comment: Proof by contradiction. If $G$ is planar then...

Comment: @tomasz Yes, you are right, thanks for pointing out. I added a remark.

Comment: @RobertZ: Okay, I've removed my comments.